# Is it possible to define a method overload for each element of a template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, overloading, c++20, parameter-pack

Suppose I have a class template with a type template parameter pack, like

```
template<typename... types>
class Foo {};
```

Is there any way I could define methods in Foo, say `void bar(T x);` with overloads for each type T in the parameter pack `types`?

Comment: To correct 1 thing you wrote:`Foo` is not a class but a class **template**. What would a class is e.g. `Foo<int>`. You could define (not simply declare) `void bar(T x) { [...] }` in the template (i.e. the class `Foo<int>` would have a defined `void bar(int x)` method) , and override it in `class MyIntFoo : public Foo<int>`. Regarding what exactly you meant in your question (I guess it was not that), what I understand is that no matter what type you pass for `T`, the implementation of `bar` from the template is not going to be the one you want; what is the point of having `bar` at all then?

Comment: @Atmo thanks, I adjusted the wording a bit. I meant to have the methods defined in the class template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `Foo` inherit each base with `void bar(T x)`:

```
template<typename T>
struct FooBase {
  void bar(T x);
};

template<typename... types>
struct Foo : FooBase<types>... {
  using FooBase<types>::bar...;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a template `bar`:

```
template<typename... types>
struct Foo
{
    template <class T>
    void bar(T x)
    {
    }
};
```

If you want to restrict to just one of `types` then you can use [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) concept:

```
template<typename... types>
struct Foo
{
    template <class T>
        requires (... || std::same_as<T, types>)
    void bar(T x)
    {
    }
};
```

But this will not accept arguments convertible to one of `types` (but not one of them). So you can use [`std::convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) instead:

```
template<typename... types>
struct Foo
{
    template <class T>
        requires (... || std::convertible_to<T, types>)
    void bar(T x)
    {
    }
};
```

This still differs a bit from having actual non-templated overloads because it will not generate "ambiguous overload error" if that's something you care about.

Comment: That's similar to an approach I was thinking of myself, and with your convertible_to suggestion should work really well! Thanks. I accepted the other answer only because it seems closer to the letter of the question in an abstract way